# I got this error from a JSON Validator - what does this mean?

Tags: json, parsing

> Parse error on line 1:
> }, {
> ^
> Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got '}'

I have never edited JSON or strings in my life and I have no idea how to troubleshoot the code for my job.

The first few lines of my code looks like this:

```
},
        {
            "include": false,
            "new_window": true,
            "pages": [
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: If your JSON starts with `},` than it's obvious syntax error - remove it

Comment: JSON can't start with a `}`, see https://www.json.org. What you've shown would be the valid *beginning* of a JSON document if you removed the `}` and `,` at the beginning.